# IPython notebook: auto-completion doesn't work after dot operators

Tags: python, autocomplete, ipython, jupyter-notebook, tab-completion

I'm novice at IPython and I've got a problem with autocompletion.
Tab autocompletion doesn't work properly.

It works after imports:

```
import<tab>
```

But tab completion doesn't work after dot operators. As example:

```
import numpy as np
np.<tab>
```

Meanwhile this example works well for IPython at console.

Package pyreadline is up-to-date. I tried different browsers. I reinstalled IPython and pyreadlines. But it didn't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write things in the same cell, it's perfectly normal. Until you've run the import line, `np` is not defined.

Run the cell once, or run the import statement in a previous cell and autocomplete should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me!

Comment: Nope! I can see how it would be, there seems to be a real problem, I am trying in a different cell having run the first.... It sucks when the simple answer does't solve the problem....

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in [an answer I found on the web](https://pretagteam.com/question/tab-autocomplete-not-working-in-jupyter-notebook):
"I've just installed the latest JEDI then helped me to solve that issue, here's the command when using Anaconda":

```
conda install - c anaconda jedi
```

"Or you might need to try this, copy this line on the top of your jupyter notebook":

```
% config Completer.use_jedi = False
```

"In my case I installed miniconda on Debian Linux and most likely had a problem with the previous Python that was included with Debian. The following lines solved my problem":

```
conda update conda
conda update--all
```